# I can't use css, javascript file in eclipse with installed phonegap plugin

Tags: javascript, android, css, eclipse, cordova

I am new to phonegap I just installed phonegap plugin for eclipse and I have created one simple app perfectly. Now I want to create an application with all js,css and javascript also I don't know how to do it so please explain how to use js,css,javascript to create an app using phonegap plugin in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any editor you have to create `html, css and javascript` files. Then copy all your html, css and javascript files inside `assets/www` and modify a bit on `MainActivity.java` (if this is your default). And add that line below.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/[Whatever entry page].html");
```

This is what it looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/[Whatever entry page].html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through phonegap official documentation to explore phonegap features.
If you have not done a single project using phonegap means you can go through this link 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html